# Explore the operation available in a REST resource

Tags: url, rest

Given a REST resource, Is there any tool or method by which I could explore the operations and additional child resources that are part of the given REST resource.

Thanks,
Vishnu.

Comment: Depends on what the server offers.  Some offer documentation.  Some don't.  As a general question, this cannot be answered.  Please clarify it by identifying a specific server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The OPTIONS method is intended to allow the server to tell you what you can do with a resource.  The only "standard" behaviour that I am aware of is that a Allow header should be returned that says which HTTP methods are allowed.  The response body could be anything, as defined by the server, but could certainly include links to child resources.

You will likely not find too many implementations of OPTIONS with response bodies with links because generally people include the links directly in the representations that are returned by the GET.